# Extra spaces after calling a newcommand

Tags: spacing, macros

I created a new command, however the spacement after calling it in the text, the there is an extra space than normal, E.G.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\numproportion}[2]{%
#1\ensuremath{\text{:}}#2
}%
\begin{document}
\noindent
\numproportion{1}{2} Daniel\\
1:2 Daniel
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes:**

**1.** I'd like to have the spacement of the second line

**2.** I used ensuremath for eventually uses inside math mode, avoiding the spacement of : in this mode

Comment: By the way, what's the purpose of `\ensuremath{\text{:}}` instead of simply `:`? If your aim is to use `\numproportion` in math mode while getting no space around `:`, the way is `\newcommand{\numproportion}[2]{#1{:}#2}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

```
\newcommand{\numproportion}[2]{%
#1{:}#2% no space here says egreg
}%
```

Comment: why does it work? is it because the various comment symbols ensure that there are no trailing spaces?

Comment: @Andrea `a<newline>b` is `a b`  but if you comment out the newline then naturally it is `ab`

Comment: oh! I hadn't realised that newline introduces a space in LaTex! Thanks

Comment: @Andrea just write a paragraph of text you'll see a newline or a space puts a space between words just as in html or most text markup systems such as the markdown used on this site